# Why is ISRO planning to launch Aditya-L1 if NASA has already launched the Parker Solar Probe?

Tags: nasa, isro, parker-solar-probe

If both the ISRO’s [Aditya-L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aditya-L1) and NASA’s [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) have almost the same key objectives,
then why is ISRO planning to launch Aditya-L1? Is there a specific reason or purpose for this decision?

Comment: Would be better to compare Aditya-1 not with Parker Solar Probe, but with SOHO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory

Comment: Because NASA itself launched Apollo 12 after Apollo 11 successfully went to the Moon and back. We don't explore things just once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are several reasons why ISRO is planning to launch Aditya-L1 even though NASA has already launched the Parker Solar Probe.

- **Different perspectives**:

  The Parker Solar Probe will fly much closer to the Sun than Aditya-L1, which will allow it to study the Sun's atmosphere in unprecedented detail. However, it will not be able to see the Sun's entire surface at once. Aditya-L1, on the other hand, will be able to see the entire Sun, but it will not be able to get as close as the Parker Solar Probe. This means that the two missions will complement each other, providing a more complete picture of the Sun.
- **Different instruments**: The Parker Solar Probe and Aditya-L1 carry different instruments, which means that they will be able to measure different things. The Parker Solar Probe's instruments are designed to study the Sun's atmosphere, while Aditya-L1's instruments are designed to study the Sun's magnetic field and solar wind.
- **Different capabilities**:

  The Parker Solar Probe is a much more complex and expensive mission than Aditya-L1. It is also a much riskier mission, as it will be exposed to much higher temperatures and radiation. Aditya-L1 is a more affordable and less risky mission, which makes it a good option for ISRO, which has a limited budget.
- **National pride**:

  There is also a sense of national pride in ISRO's Aditya-L1 mission. ISRO is India's space agency, and the Aditya-L1 mission is a major milestone for the agency. It is a sign that India is capable of carrying out cutting-edge space missions.

Overall, the Aditya-L1 mission is a valuable addition to the Parker Solar Probe mission. It will provide a different perspective on the Sun, and it will use different instruments to measure different things. This will help scientists to learn more about the Sun and its effects on our solar system.

Comment: Worth mentioning as a part of natnl pride: part of it is also just "do our scientists get the data they want". Take Hubble as an example--it's got a very full waitlist. If you launch & operate the mission, you get to prioritize your guys first.